# S3: Access Denied on action Get Object Attributes of SSE-C encrypted object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy, aws-permissions

User has full s3 access policy applied.

Encryption key and algorithm (AES256) are provided and the same user can **put and get an encrypted object**, but not its attributes because of an access denied error.

Why does S3 replies with an error on "Get Object Attributes" action call for an encrypted object with a customer provided encryption key (SSE-C) ? How to fix that ?

Comment: Presumably your credentials have s3:GetObjectAttributes permission. Which headers are you sending? Needs to be x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm, x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key, and x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-MD5.